# Haskell multiple tuple check in list

Tags: haskell

Say I have a list of elements in this format
(U "NAME", I "Item Name", INT_HERE)
I would like to make a function that takes a U, an I and checks if they exist in that list in any of the elements and return true if yes, else otherwise.
for example

```
exists (U "John") (I "Sofa") 
[(U "Mark" , I "Legion Y520", 5),
(U "Ahmed" ,I "GTX 1060", 3),
(U "Carole" , I "BMW C-Class", 5),
(U "John" , I "Maximized outlet", 4),
(U "Malik" , I "Honda Civic", 1)]
```

should return **False**

this is the code I have tried using(extractitem and extractuser both extract the first and second part of the item properly and I have tested them, issue should be with this part)

```
exists :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> [(a,b,c)] -> Bool
exists y z [] = False
exists y z (x:xs) = if ((extractuser x) == y) then if ((extractitem x) == 
z) then True else False else exists y z xs
```

and this is the error im getting

```
Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : exists
*** Expected type : (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> [(a,b,c)] -> Bool
*** Inferred type : (Eq a, Eq a) => a -> a -> [(a,a,b)] -> Bool
```

I would also like to make a second function get that has the same functionality with the difference that it actually displays the element which the conditions applies to / give out an error message if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `else hasRating y z xs` shouldn't it be `exists`? Also take a look at any http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any , and learn to use https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ to easily find base functions that you can use as a construction blocks.

Comment: same error after changing

Comment: What is the code for the `extract*` functions?
Most likely you have the same code for `extractuser ` and `extractitem` (copy/paster error).

Comment: Oh, is this `hugs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this entirely with pattern matching. Your current error *appears* to be a typo, but pattern matching is more straightforward and serves to eliminate some of those errors.

```
exists :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> [(a, b, c)] -> Bool
exists u i ((u', i', _):xs) = u == u' && i == i' || exists u i xs
exists _ _ []               = False
```

or with less explicit recursion:

```
exists :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> [(a, b, c)] -> Bool
exists u i = any (\(u', i', _) -> u==u' && i==i')
```

---

The error message

```
Inferred type is not general enough  
*** Expression    : exists  
*** Expected type : (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> [(a,b,c)] -> Bool  
*** Inferred type : (Eq a, Eq a) => a -> a -> [(a,a,b)] -> Bool
```

seems to indicate that your `extractitem` function is doing:

```
extractitem (x, _, _) = x
```

when it should be

```
extractitem (_, y, _) = y
```

Comment: You're actually right my extractitem was flawed as you described, both it and your method works, thanks for the help man you rock.

Comment: @OmarHussein awesome, glad I could help!

Comment: I'd just like to note that your approach only checks a single tuple as opposed to the list I wanted to check in the question, I used it as a helper method and iterated over the list.

Comment: exists is missing the base case: `exists _ _ [] = False`